# Coefficient of $x^k$ in expansion of $(1+x)(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3)\cdots(1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^n)$ under modulo 2?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions

Is there any general formula for finding coefficient of $x^k$ in $(1+x)(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3)\cdots(1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots+x^n)$ under modulo 2?

Comment: Look for Mahonian triangle.

Comment: There are simple ways of computing them. The coefficients of the polynomial form kind of like a "Pascal's triangle" kind of pattern where the coefficients at a given level is the sum of the coefficients on the line above. If you write it down you will see all kinds of patterns there.